# How to escape attachment image caption text?

Tags: php, escaping

I'm outputting an attachment image's caption but feel I should escape the output:

```
<figcaption>
    <?php echo get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() )->post_excerpt; ?>
</figcaption>
```

I was tempted to use `esc_html( get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() )->post_excerpt )` but the caption may contain legitimate markup such as `<a href=""></a>` etc.

How should I escape image attachment caption text considering it may contain markup I'd like to keep?

Comment: `get_post()` already have a lot of filters which handles sanitation of the post object, so IMO you do not need extra sanitation

Comment: My understanding is you should always late escape (i.e. at the point of output)?